# Swift Parse Query For PFGeoPoint Not Displaying Multiple Annotations

Tags: swift, dictionary, parse-platform, annotations

I'm having a problem when trying to display multiple annotations saved as PFGeoPoints to my map. When I run my query it's working fine, however it is only displaying the most recently saved annotation on the map, when instead I need it to display every annotation that has been saved to date.

Here's my code:

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "location")

    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in


        if let brandsLocation = objects {

            for object in brandsLocation {

                if let brandLocation = object as? PFObject {

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()


                let annotationPoint = object["geoPoint"] as! PFGeoPoint

                    self.annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(annotationPoint.latitude, annotationPoint.longitude)

                    self.annotation.title = brandLocation["annotationTitle"] as? String

                    self.annotation.subtitle = brandLocation["annotationSubtitle"] as? String

                    self.map.addAnnotation(self.annotation)




            }

        }

    }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated, I know it's probably a small problem that is causing not all my annotations to be queried. Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see how many times you are going through the loop while iterating through objects?

Comment: No I haven't seen I'm not too familiar with breakpoints. Could you suggest where to place them? I would think after each of the four braces at the end of my code.

Comment: No you'd want one  at `if let brandLocation...` and see how many times it hits. If it only hits once, you're hitting only one single object for some reason, which is why you're getting only one annotation. If it hits multiple times, you would then wanna step through and see the values you end up setting for the annotation's properties.

Comment: It's definitely hitting more than once, three times actually for the three annotations that I have. However, only one is still displaying

Comment: Is there something specific about annotations that would result in a query only yielding one annotation?

Comment: I haven't worked with Apple Maps annotations. Perhaps only one can be displayed at a time on a map? Is the annotation that is displayed the first, or the last that you are iterating through?  And verify that each time you iterate through to create a new annotation you are creating it with different data. Put a breakpoint at `self.map.addAnotation...` and verify the data that was put into it / what it's holding.

Comment: Wait I think it's the self.annotation vs annotation

Comment: That was it!!! Simple solution, I removed "self" from annotation and it worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to check my answer as correct then, please ;)

Answer (score 1):

You use `self.annotation...` when setting the properties of your annotation and adding it to the map, so the `let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()` property is going unused. You must have declared a separate annotation as part of the class scope that is being used here, rather than the local one within your loop.

In the future, show your whole code and maybe point out the relevant separately, it makes issues like this way easier to spot from someone who hasn't worked with the code base yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referencing wrong in the title and subtitle. These values must be unique.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "location")
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

    if error != nil {
        print(error ?? "")
    }

    if objects != nil {
        for object in objects {

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            if let annotationPoint = object["geoPoint"] as? PFGeoPoint {
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(annotationPoint.latitude, annotationPoint.longitude)
                annotation.title = object["annotationTitle"] as? String
                annotation.subtitle = object["annotationSubtitle"] as? String
                self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you functionally change? All the changes appear to be style changes, except you don't cast object to PFObject, and you changed `let annotationPoint...` to `if let annotationPoint...`

Did I miss something? The `if let brandLocation...` being removed shouldn't have done anything since it was nested in the for loop, so I don't think it'd be a conflict of immutable value not getting set.

Comment: Yeah this seemed to result in the same problem

Comment: agreed, my answer was wrong. I've added my code to match Jake T. answer.